# UWP приостанавливает работу GUI-потока при отключении пользователя

Tags: uwp

Я написал UWP приложение, которое ведет постоянный обмен данными через сокет с приложениями Win32.

Основная проблема в том, что пока я подключен к компьютеру на котором моё приложение установлено напрямую или удаленно через RDP, обмен сообщениями идет и всё в порядке. Но как только я прекращаю пользовательскую сессию, приложения Win32 продолжают работать и отправлять сообщения через сокет, а вот UWP приложение перестает их принимать, пока я снова не подключусь к компьютеру.

Можно ли что-нибудь сделать, чтобы UWP-приложение продолжало работать и без пользовательской сессии? На сколько я понял приостанавливает работу основной GUI-поток UWP-приложения, в котором так уж получилось принимаются все сообщения через сокет. Можно ли как-то отменить приостановку работы этого потока?